# A hard combinatorial identity

Tags: co.combinatorics

I asked this questions on the https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1016713/ But I don't get answer.
I try to prove the following hypothesis
$$\sum_{i=0}^{min\{k, n-1\}}(-1)^i { n+i-1 \choose i}{{n+k-2} \choose k-i} {n+2k-i-1 \choose 2k}= \sum_{i=0}^{\min\{k, n-3\}}{{n-3} \choose i}{{n-2} \choose i} {{2n+k-i-4} \choose {k-i}}\frac{1}{i+1}$$
Calculation in the Maple shows that 
$$\sum_{i=0}^{min\{k, n-1\}}(-1)^i { n+i-1 \choose i}{{n+k-2} \choose k-i} {n+2k-i-1 \choose 2k}= \sum_{i=0}^{\min\{k, n-3\}}{{n-3} \choose i}{{n-2} \choose i} {{2n+k-i-4} \choose {k-i}}\frac{1}{i+1}=\sum_{i=0}^{k}(-1)^i { n+i-1 \choose i}{{n+k-2} \choose k-i} {n+2k-i-1 \choose 2k}= \sum_{i=0}^{k}{{n-3} \choose i}{{n-2} \choose i} {{2n+k-i-4} \choose {k-i}}\frac{1}{i+1}=
{\frac {{n+k-1\choose k}{n-2+k\choose k}}{k+1}}$$
Here are some attempts.- 
$$ \sum_{i=0}^{min\{k, n-1\}}(-1)^i { n+i-1 \choose i}{{n+k-2} \choose k-i} {n+2k-i-1 \choose 2k}=\\= \sum_{i=0}^{min\{k, n-1\}} { -n \choose i}{{n+k-2} \choose k-i} {n+2k-i-1 \choose 2k}=\\=
\sum_{i=0}^{min\{k, n-1\}} \frac{(-1)^i(n+i-1)(n+k-2)!}{i!(k-i)!(n-1)!} {n+2k-i-1 \choose 2k} =\\=\sum_{i=0}^{min\{k, n-1\}} \frac{(-1)^i(n+i-1)(n+k-1)!k!}{i!(k-i)!k!(n-1)!(n+k-1)} {n+2k-i-1 \choose 2k}= \\ = {n+k-1 \choose k}\sum_{i=0}^{min\{k, n-1\}} \frac{(-1)^i(n+i-1)}{(n+k-1)} {k \choose i} {n+2k-i-1 \choose 2k}.$$
This is my attempt so far. I tried use Mathematical induction method (about k) and Chu's Theorem. The second way was using formula ${r+k+1 \choose k}=\sum_{i=0}^k {r+i \choose i}.$ I cannot prove it.
Help me, please.

Comment: Dividing it up in a few cases, each of them should be provable (via computer) with Zeilbergers algorithm.

Comment: if I understand the question correctly, Maple has already proven this identity, and even given a closed form expression for the sum, presumably using Zeilberger.

Comment: @Per Alexandersson I can not use Zeilbergers algorithm in Maple. please tell me what files need  I download?

Comment: Zeilbergers algorithm is build-in in Maple. GIYF.
http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=SumTools/Hypergeometric/Zeilberger